# .NET threading like Node.js/V8?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I've been away from .NET desktop programming for some time, while drinking the Node.js koolaid.  There are some parts of Node.js I find easy to work with.  In particular, I like the simplicity of the threading model, and that I can have a few of the benefits of a multithreaded application while only writing code to keep track of a single thread.

Now, I have a need to write a multi-threaded application in .NET, and it occurred to me that there is no reason I cannot use a similar [threading model that is used to build Node.js applications](http://www.aaronstannard.com/image.axd?picture=nodejs%20for%20dotnet_thumb.png).  In particular, I want to:

- Call long-running functions with callback parameters.  (That function would execute on a thread from a pool.  Maybe a simple wrapper function to call functions on new threads would be sufficient?)
- Have those callback function calls ran on the "main" thread for processing
- Maintain automatic synchronization for all objects accessed by this "main" thread, so locking isn't an issue

Does such a framework for this threading model already exist within, or for .NET applications?  If not, are there parts of .NET that already support or handle some of the functionality that I am seeking?

Comment: I'd look into async/await functionality in .net4.5. While not quite so cushioned from the world of concurrency and multithreading as with node, it's the best model I've used for dealing with asynchronicity.

Comment: @spender, Thanks for the advice, I am reading up on it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the TPL. Here’s an example of how it works

```
Void Work()
{
    Task<string> ts = Get();
    ts.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
        string result = t.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        });
}
```

There are a whole range of possibilities for cancelation, error handling using different schedulers etc. With .Net 4.5 you have the possibility of using await

```
async void Work()
{ 
    Task<string> ts = Get(); 
    string result = await ts; 
    Console.WriteLine(result); 
}
```

Here the compiler looks at methods marked async and adds a whole pile of thread safe robust task synchronizing code while leaving the code readable.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, `async` / `await` is an excellent choice for .NET. In particular:

- `Task` / `Task<T>` / `TaskCompletionSource<T>` [are analogous to](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/thinking-about-async-tasks.html) JavaScript's `Deferred` / `Promise` / `Future`.
- It's [pretty easy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/15/implementing-then-with-await.aspx) to create JavaScript-style continuations using .NET-style continuations, but for the most part you won't need them.
- There is no JavaScript equivalent to `async` / `await`. `async` allows you to write your methods as though they were synchronous, and under the hood it breaks them up into continuations wherever there's an `await`. So you don't have to use continuation passing style.
- For operations on a background thread, your best choice is `Task.Run`. However, the standard pattern for .NET is to have the background operation compute and return a *single* value, instead of having continuous bidirectional messaging with the main thread.
- If you do need a "stream" of asynchronous data, you should use [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) or [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609). This is where things diverge from JS quite a bit.

I recommend you start with my [`async` / `await` intro post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a look at TPL (Task Parallel Library) which became available in .Net 4.0. It can do points 1 and 2 but not 3.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: Thanks Richard, that goes a long way towards what I am seeking.  I will likely use it for my project.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved, among other options, by taking advantage of Window's native event loop.

Following code is a POC for the same and it addresses all the 3 points you have mentioned.
But note that it is just a POC. It is not type safe and it uses Delegate.DynamicInvoke which can be slow but it proves the concept nevertheless.

```
public static class EventLoop
{
    private class EventTask
    {
        public EventTask(Delegate taskHandler) : this(taskHandler, null) {}

        public EventTask(Delegate taskHandler, Delegate callback)
        {
            TaskHandler = taskHandler;
            Callback = callback;
        }

        private Delegate Callback {get; set;}

        private Delegate TaskHandler {get; set;}

        public void Invoke(object param)
        {
            object[] paramArr = null;
            if (param.GetType().Equals(typeof(object[])))
            {
                paramArr = (object[]) param; //So that DynamicInvoke does not complain
            }

            object res = null;

            if (TaskHandler != null)
            {
                if (paramArr != null)
                {
                    res = TaskHandler.DynamicInvoke(paramArr);
                }
                else
                {
                    res = TaskHandler.DynamicInvoke(param);
                }
            }

            if (Callback != null)
            {
                EnqueueSyncTask(Callback, res);
            }
        }
    }

    private static WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext _syncContext;
    public static void Run(Action<string[]> mainProc, string[] args)
    {
        //You need to reference System.Windows.Forms
        _syncContext = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
        EnqueueSyncTask(mainProc, args);
        Application.Run();
    }

    public static void EnqueueSyncTask(Delegate taskHandler, object param)
    {
        //All these tasks will run one-by-one in order on Main thread
        //either on call of Application.DoEvenets or when Main thread becomes idle
        _syncContext.Post(new EventTask(taskHandler).Invoke, param);
    }

    public static void EnqueueAsyncTask(Delegate taskHandler, object param, Delegate callback)
    {
       //En-queue on .Net Thread Pool
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new EventTask(taskHandler, callback).Invoke, param);
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MAIN THREAD";
        Console.WriteLine("Method Main: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        EventLoop.Run(MainProc, args);
    }

    static void MainProc(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method MainProc: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Queuing Long Running Task...");
        EventLoop.EnqueueAsyncTask(new Func<int,int,int>(LongCalculation), new object[]{5,6}, new Action<int>(PrintResult));
        Console.WriteLine("Queued Long Running Task");

        Thread.Sleep(400); //Do more work
        EventLoop.EnqueueAsyncTask(new Func<int, int, int>(LongCalculation), new object[] { 15, 16 }, new Action<int>(PrintResult));
        Thread.Sleep(150); //Do some more work but within this time 2nd task is not able to complete, meanwhile 1st task completes

        //Long running Tasks will run in background but callback will be executed only when Main thread becomes idle
        //To execute the callbacks before that, call Application.DoEvents
        Application.DoEvents(); //PrintResult for 1st task as 2nd is not yet complete
        Console.WriteLine("Method MainProc: Working over-time!!!!");
        Thread.Sleep(500); //After this sleep, 2nd Task's print will also be called as Main thread will become idle
    }

    static int LongCalculation(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method LongCalculation, Is Thread Pool Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
        Console.WriteLine("Running Long Calculation");
        Thread.Sleep(500); //long calc
        Console.WriteLine("completed Long Calculation");
        return a + b;
    }

    static void PrintResult(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method PrintResult: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + a);
        //Continue processing potentially queuing more long running tasks
    }
```

Output:

[image]